# Howto update multiple github projects generated from a single fork?

Tags: git, github

So I have a fork, which I use as a template for various projects.

When I update the fork (master) from the upstream, I then want to update each subsequent project.

A. At the moment I follow the following steps for each new project:

1. Create new github project and clone to disk
2. Clone fork to disk
3. Delete contents from the new project folder, and copy across contents from the cloned fork
4. npm install (new project)

B. When the fork is updated

1. backup project src files, then delete project contents
2. copy across updated fork contents o project folder, and reinstate project src files
3. npm install (project)

Is there a more effective way to resolve updating each project from the updated fork?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating new project

1. Create new repository on Github. Do not clone
2. Clone fork with remote named `upstream` into folder with new project name

   ```
   git clone -o upstream https://github.com/<user>/<fork>.git <my_new_project_name>
   ```
3. Add new repository url remote `origin`, push, and set to track

   ```
   cd <my_new_project_name>
   git remote add origin https://github.com/<user>/<my_new_project_name>.git
   git push -u origin master
   ```
4. npm install

Updating

```
git pull upstream master
```

Comment: Jeff, when I make changes to files in my <my_new_project_name> and then commit/push, the changes are being pushed to the fork (upstream) instead of <my_new_project_name> (master). This is incorrect. How do I resolve this?

Comment: @TheoG you need to change your default tracking branch. `git push -u origin master`

Comment: Jeff, I did 'git push -u origin master' but am getting the following error, '! [rejected] master -> master (non-fast-forward)'

Comment: Jeff, doing 'git push --force origin master' updates the repository as required